# How to generate a particular type of size-frequency histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have attached an example image of a specific format of size-frequency histogram that I am interested in using, however I have not been able to figure out how to create it in R. I do not see this rather unique histogram discussed in other threads.

Y-axis is size classes (in my case increments of 1mm from 0 to 15).

X-axis is one calendar year in successive months (in my case beginning with FEB 2014 thru JAN 2015).

The width of each horizontal bar depicts the proportional contribution of each size class.

The sum of all bars in each month represents 100% (of the organisms in the sample that month).

Generic data can be generated for the purposes of attempting to create this histogram, e.g. n=x for any given month and randomly generated sizes (lengths) from 0.5mm to 14.5mm. These types of histograms that I see in the literature seem to be generated by institutional users of very expensive stat programs that I do not have access to. I think that it would be great (not just for me) if a how-to template could be created for R users. This type of histogram is important to biologists studying secondary production in order to visualize life-history characteristics - in my case stream insects.[image: size-frequency histogram]

Comment: Ask this on stack exchange and you will receive more attention as this is more focused on coding

Comment: Have you gotten a response else where, yet? I have also been searching how to make this for head capsule width of dragonfly nymphs.

Comment: @Red was correct: this post should have been migrated to [SO].  It's too late to do that now.